# How should one handle Register/Login when they are both identical flows?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, login, registration

I am building a website where the *only* login option is Stack Exchange. As a result, it doesn't matter if the user is registered or not, it's easy enough for me to create the same workflow for both, and to be completely fair, it's easier to share the workflow.

As a result, I don't really *need* Register **and** Login. The question is, when dealing with users, what option would make the most sense?

1. Keep **Register** and **Login**
2. Keep **Register** or **Login**
3. Change Register and Login to single **Sign-in with Stack Exchange**

I'm not sure which of these options is best, since this website won't really have a Register / Login user flow, it's only 'Sign-In'. If you're unregistered then you are immediately registered, if you are previously registered then you are immediately logged in.

Comment: The third, sign in with [X] seems to be the most common approach. The user would probably have used oauth login previously and would know what to do. Other option is to go with something like "personalise using Stack Exchange"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having the same situation with my platform but with Facebook's social login as the only register option.

We went for two buttons:

- Continue using Facebook.
- I don't want to use Facebook.

When the user clicks 'Continue using Facebook', he either registers or logs in if he has registered before. However, the user could not have Facebook or does not want to use it to login. This can also happen with your flow. When a user clicks 'I don't want to use Facebook' he gets redirected to a page where we explain why we only use Facebook's social login. There's a button on that page to continue using Facebook after all and a 'return to main' button.

**This is our flow (low fidelity version)**

[image]

**Research**

I'm currently in the process of testing this solution.

We've based our decisions on user interviews. Over 90% of the people we've asked say they always use social login to register and login on websites they visit. These were just interviews, of course. We're currently in the final preparations to test our new flow with a closed beta group to see if it works in practice also.

Comment: What's the point of requiring Facebook though? You would lose me as a customer for example, as I deactivated my FB long ago.